# Instantiate new element class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How can I instantiate an existing div element using javascript? Lets say I have:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="myclass">TROLL FACE</div>
    </div>
```

I want to create as many 'myclass' element inside the 'container' class as I want using javascript. How can I do this?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var container = $('.container');
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    container.append('<div class="myclass">TROLL FACE</div>');
}
```

You could use the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

Comment: Yes, of course that I have tried it. It works perfectly fine. Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KQ7jb/

Comment: Thanks, for some reason its not working when I just put it on a script tag over the head. I have to put it on an external js because I am using one.

Comment: This code seems to require the jQuery Framework. I recommend you to use a JS-Framework, because it handle many Crossbrowser problems for you. If you want a solution without jQuery edit your question

Answer (score 2):

You may want the [.clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

```
var ele = $('.myclass');

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ele.clone().appendTo('.container');
}
```

***[The live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ekTrM/)***

Comment: Hi, have you tried this code? I dont know but its not working on me.

Comment: @user1577161 Added the demo, check it.

Answer (score 1):

With or without JQuery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < howMany; ++i) {
    // pure js
    var div = document.createElement('div')
    div.classList.add('myclass')
    somePlace.appendChild(div)

    // jquery
    $("<div></div>").addClass('myclass').appendTo(somePlace)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="myclass">TROLL FACE</div>
</div>

var $container = $('.container');
var $myclass = $('.container').html();

var mycount ; // Your count

for(var i =0;i< mycount ; i++){
   $container.append($myclass)
}
```